# Cube that turns every for example 5 seconds 90 degrees

Tags: unity, rotation

I want a cube to rotate 90 degrees every [Second/Counter should be setable]

Like in this video at 3.47 the spiky cube that turns 90 degrees
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxWpsT4lKXU

I have tried to do it but it will not turn 90 degrees smoothly or even 90 degrees, it just turns kind of 90 degrees but I need help I guess.

Here is my script:

---

public class TurnCubeScript : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Transform turnCube;

public float turnSpeed;
//SETTING THE COUNTER FOR OBJECT TO TURN
public float setCounter;
public float counter;
//SETTING THE COUNTER TO SETCOUNTER AFTER COUNTER1 = 0
public float setCounter1;
public float counter1;

void Start () 
{
    setCounter = counter + setCounter;
    setCounter1 = counter1 + setCounter1;
}

void Update () 
{
    TurnTheCube();
}

void TurnTheCube()
{

    counter -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
    if (counter < 1)
    {
        //SOME TRIES... 
        //turnCube.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3 (0, 0, 90 * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
        //turnCube.Rotate(0, 0, 90 * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
        //turnCube.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotation);

        counter1 -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;

        //GIVES THE CUBE SOME TIME TO TURN
        if(counter1 < 1)
        {
            counter = setCounter;
            counter1 = setCounter1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a stationary rotating box, you should try using the built in script "auto rotate and translate" and set it to your box. Then, type in the values of how you want it to rotate it.

Comment: its worth noting that `AutoRotateAndTranslate` is a class member of the `StandardAssets.Utility` namespace. You will have to import the asset package before it is available.